# How to Moq a method in C# whose input parameter is of type Enum

Tags: c#, unit-testing, enums, mocking, moq

How to Moq a method  in C# whose input parameter is of type Enum?

```
 Moq.MockRepository mock = new Moq.MockRepository(MockBehaviour.Loose);
    var myInstance =mock.Create<IMyMethod>();
    myInstance.SetUp(x=>x.myMethod(It.IsAny<**`EnumType`**>()).Verifiable();
```

How to Give ENUMType here

Comment: IsAny is a method so it needs () behind it. Besides that i think it should work. What error do you get?

Comment: I have used method() But it wont work and im getting below error.
Any Expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments

Comment: @SreenivasKalyan Show the **actual** method you are trying to mock. Otherwise we are left guessing what is the **actual** problem.

Comment: If IMyMethod.myMethod has additional optional parameters you have to name them all with Moq.

Comment: you are geneious @Ralf  It worked out... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to do the following.

```
mock.Setup(s => s.YourMethod(It.IsAny<YourEnumType>())).Verifiable();
```

Obviously, remember to put the using statements linking this file to wherever you have your enum type saved.

Also as an extra note. To make this dynamic (So you don't just take any, you actually use the value coming in to decide what your mock returns) you can do the following

```
 mock.Setup(s => s.YourMethod(It.IsAny<YourEnumType>()))
 .ReturnsAsync((YourEnymType enumType)
 => yourMock.Where(x => x.EnumValue == enumType).SingleOrDefault());
```

Notice This is done for async, if you're not doing an asynchronous, switch the "ReturnsAsync" to a "Returns"

Comment: I can also see you've mentioned your method also has additional parameters, you also need to name them all.
I.e: mock.Setup(s => s.YourMethod(It.IsAny<YourEnumType>, It.IsAny<string>())); //assuming you have a string that is optional in YourMethod